# How to get JSON data from a PHP file to print in html file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP file that outputs JSON from the MySQL database, I wanted to get that JSON output into HTML file and display as a table. It works fine when I use the JSON output as it is, but I wanted to take that PHP file as a URL or as a file and get the result as a table in the HTML file.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$DBServer="localhost";
$DBUser="root";
$DBPass="";
$DBName="test";
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
$sql='SELECT userinfo.id, name, user_id, posts FROM userinfo, user_posts WHERE userinfo.id = user_posts.user_id';



$rs=$conn->query($sql);
$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);



?>
```

HTML CODE:

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

      // Need to take PHP URL or file name instead of JSON data

     var data = {
        "report":  [{
            "id": "Abril",
            "name": "13",
            "user_id": "Lisboa",

        }]
      };  



      // Loop through data.report instead of data
      for (var i = 0; i < data.report.length; i++) {
        var tr = $('<tr/>');

        // Indexing into data.report for each td element
        $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].id+ "</td>");
        $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].name+ "</td>");
        $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].user_id+ "</td>");

        $('.table1').append(tr);
      }
    });
    </script>

    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table1 table"  >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>USER ID</th>


                             </tr>
                        </thead>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Check ajac call for load data from php to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `fetch` api to load the data from the php file and display on the screen as table.

Example.

```
(async function() {
  try {
    let tableEle = document.getElementById("content");
    let response = await fetch("<php file url>");
    let body = await response.json();
    let rows = "";
    for (const item of body) {
      rows += `<tr>
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.name}<t/d>
        <td>${item.user_id}</td>
      </tr>`;
    }
    tableEle.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = rows;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table1 table" id="content">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>User ID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Working sample with jsonplaceholder api.**

```js
(async function() {
  try {
    let tableEle = document.getElementById("content");
    let response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    let body = await response.json();
    let rows = "";
    for (const item of body) {
      rows += `<tr>
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.title}</td>
        <td>${item.userId}</td>
      </tr>`;
    }
    tableEle.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = rows;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

```css
#content {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #content td,
  #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  #content tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }

  #content tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  #content th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table1 table" id="content">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>UserID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it return a blank html page with no errors in the console.

Comment: <?php
$DBServer="localhost";
$DBUser="root";
$DBPass="";
$DBName="test";
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
$sql='SELECT userinfo.id, name, user_id, posts FROM userinfo, user_posts WHERE userinfo.id = user_posts.user_id';
 


$rs=$conn->query($sql);
$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);

 

?>

Comment: user_post is a table name.

Comment: ya. it's a query of two table joins. user_posts is a table and user_id is a column in that table.

Comment: there is no response

Comment: The backend code is working fine. still, I need to check?

Comment: [{"id":"1","name":"aa","user_id":"1","posts":"blog"},{"id":"1","name":"aa","user_id":"1",

Comment: it's goes on like this.

Comment: I tried the code you updated for me there is no data available what you are getting.http://localhost:8081/mohamed-ashif/fetch.php it's my php file i am accessing.

Comment: ya i have seen the output you shared. i don't get an error same blank page as i said earlier with this code also. Should I change some thing else?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Mohamed.

Since you are using already jQuery I would perhaps use their ajax functionality. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://server.example.org/index.php',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {              
       // Here you add your functionality after the call has succeeded.
       // alert('Data: ' + data); 

       // Loop through data.report instead of data
       for (var i = 0; i < data.report.length; i++) {
         var tr = $('<tr/>');

         // Indexing into data.report for each td element
         $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Mes + "</td>");
         $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Dia + "</td>");
         $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Local + "</td>");

         $('.table1').append(tr);
      }
    },
    error: function(request, error) {
        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Comment: it return a blank html page with no errors in the console.

Comment: @MohamedAshif Did you tried to uncomment the `alert('Data: ' + data)` inside the success function and adopt this code example to your requirements?

Comment: @MohamedAshif I'm not sure if I fully understand your answer but maybe you should  uncomment the part and check the values of data? From your given example I don't see how your php script is returning the data.

Comment: <?php
$DBServer="localhost";
$DBUser="root";
$DBPass="";
$DBName="test";
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
$sql='SELECT userinfo.id, name, user_id, posts FROM userinfo, user_posts WHERE userinfo.id = user_posts.user_id';
 


$rs=$conn->query($sql);
$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);

 

?>

Comment: it's my PHP script, It joins two tables and gets the data in JSON format.

Comment: Ok, I see that you're missing at least the `Content-Type`-header in your response. This is required for `$.ajax`. Can you add `header('Content-Type: application/json');`; before your first `echo`-statement?

Comment: And what do you get if you uncomment the `alert()` part? Can you add the response from your php-script into your question and adjust your question with your most recent version of the code? It's quite hard to do this kind of debug w/o having the full code version.

Comment: when i uncomment the alert it gives a popup shows Data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...

Comment: Ok so it seems you got the response correctly because it looks like an list of objects. In my opinion I would replace the `alert(data)` with `console.log(data)`. This will show you the structure of `data`. With this you can then adopt your iteration to fill the table.

Comment: Alternative: You can adopt your php code to the same structure as you had it inside your javascript. You can achieve this with `echo json_encode(['report => $data]);`. Then your existing code might be working already.
`

Comment: Replaced with console.log(data) but still the page is blank

Comment: `console.log()` is in this case writing to the DevTools Console. Did you checked the DevTools in your browser?

Comment: yes. under the network tab I can see status code 200 OK

Comment: It should be under "Console" tab. To make it more obvious you can also perform `console.log('MY DATA', data);` and then you can search in the "Console" tab for MY DATA.

Comment: in the console it shows undefined when i paste console.log()